# What to return from an IQueryable when I don't have something to filter?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

```
public static IQueryable<CustItemTrades> SeriesIdFilter(this 
IQueryable<CustItemTrades> trades, List<short?> lastPriceDocs) =>
    lastPriceDocs != null ? trades.Where(c => lastPriceDocs.Contains(c.SeriesId)) :
// what to return here if my List<short> == null
```

When my `List<short?>` is `null` it means that I don't have something to filter in my query. What to return then?

Comment: It's not clear what you actually want the return value to be. If no filter is passed in, don't you just want to return `trades` directly and unfiltered?

Comment: And when you say "it doesn't work", in what way does it not work? Tell us the error messages you get or we can't really help.

Comment: The question is unclear. As you said, if the list of values is empty, you don't want to filter. So don't filter and return the original query. `IQueryable` is a query, not a container or list of values. Just return `trades`. *Don't* use the Elvis operator just to put everything in a single line though.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, I think you meant to say _ternary if_. The Elvis operator in C# is `?.` or `??`, depending on your definition.

Comment: @Orion those are the "new" ones. We were talking about ?: as the Elvis operator before `?.` and `??`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, there is no `?:` operator in Sotiris's code either, though - only the ternary if construct of `A ? B : C`.

Comment: Ok guys you are right i did not present my question well. Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos you approach works silly of me not to consider what you said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach does not work because `Enumerable.Empty` returns *nothing*, but you want to return all, if i have understood your requirement correctly.

> When my List is null it means that i dont have something to filter in
> my query

If you don't have something to filter, then don't filter.

```
public static IQueryable<CustItemTrades> SeriesIdFilter(this IQueryable<CustItemTrades> trades, List<short?> lastPriceDocs)
{
    if(lastPriceDocs == null)
    {
        return trades;
    }
    
    return trades.Where(c => lastPriceDocs.Contains(c.SeriesId));
}
```

Don't modify the query so that the `Where` matches always, simply return everything.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Possibly because the question isn't really possible to answer due to it being unclear? The hint from the OP is that is should be an empty list, not an unfiltered list?

Comment: @DavidG: where OP says that it must be an empty list? You cannot draw conclusions out of code that does not give the expected result.

Comment: @DavidG in that case there's a misunderstanding about what IQueryable is

Comment: Like I said, it's an unclear and confusing question.

Comment: Unfortunately, due to the Azuritis pandemic of the last decade, new developers have no way to learn about .NET any more. You need to already know the basics in order to find the good courses, blogs and separate good SO answers from copy pasta.